# ORACLE Optimizar consultas con not exists y dblink

Tags: oracle, revisión-de-código

Con el not exists se demora 1 min.

```
    SELECT
    PED.NFCH         "NFCH",
    PED.NFCHF         "NFCHF",   
    PED.CNL         "CNL",
    PED.CLI         "CLI",
    PED.GRC       "GRC"
    FROM
    PE@DBV PED
    WHERE 
    PED.NFCH =  20160201 AND  ---P_FECHA
    PED.CNL = 1 and  -- P_CEDI
    PED.CLI <> 0
    and NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CLIENTE CLI WHERE CLI.IN_INTER = 'AG' AND CLI.CODIGO = PED.CLI) 
    GROUP BY 
    PED.NFCH ,
    PED.NFCHF ,      
    PED.CNL,
    PED.CLI ,        
    PED.GRC 

    Pero sin el  not exists se demora 3 segundos

      SELECT
    PED.NFCH         "NFCH",
    PED.NFCHF         "NFCHF",   
    PED.CNL         "CNL",
    PED.CLI         "CLI",
    PED.GRC       "GRC"
    FROM
    PE@DBV PED
    WHERE 
    PED.NFCH =  20160201 AND  ---P_FECHA
    PED.CNL = 1 and  -- P_CEDI
    PED.CLI <> 0
    --and NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CLIENTE CLI WHERE CLI.IN_INTER = 'AG' AND CLI.CODIGO = PED.CLI) 
    GROUP BY 
    PED.NFCH ,
    PED.NFCHF ,      
    PED.CNL,
    PED.CLI ,        
    PED.GRC
```

Comment: Nota: `NOT EXISTS` es increíblemente lento en todos los motores que he utilizado: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, Informix. Una mejor estrategia para eso es utilizar `LEFT JOIN` en lo posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para optimizar el not exists lo realice usando un left join y un filtro de is null. de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT
    PED.NFCH         "NFCH",
    PED.NFCHF         "NFCHF",   
    PED.CNL         "CNL",
    PED.CLI         "CLI",
    PED.GRC       "GRC"
    FROM
    PEDIDO@DBVNSLLNG PED, CLI CLI
    WHERE 
    PED.CLI = CLI.CODIGO (+) AND
    PED.NFCH =  20160201 AND  ---P_FECHA
    PED.CNL = 1 and  -- P_CEDI
    PED.CLI <> 0 AND
    CLI.CODIGO IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
    PED.NFCH ,
    PED.NFCHF ,      
    PED.CNL,
    PED.CLI ,        
    PED.GRC
```